# A variable won't update when a scale bar on python tkinter is moved

Tags: python, tkinter

whenever I run my code the variable infection_rate doesn't change when the user interacts with the sliding scale (0 to 100). I've tried changing IntVar to IntVar() and vice versa but it has no effect.

```
from tkinter import *
from epidemic import World


class MyEpidemicModel:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.height = 500
        self.width = 500
        #self.infection_rate = 30
        self.infection_rate = IntVar()
        self.rate = Scale(orient='horizontal', from_=0, to=100, variable=self.infection_rate)
        self.rate.pack()
        self.infection_radius = (self.infection_rate/2)

        self.master = master
        master.title("An Epidemic Model")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our Epidemic Model")
        self.label.pack()
        
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, width = self.width, height = self.height)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.inputCanvas = Canvas()

        self.start = Button(master, text="Start", command=self.start_epidemic)
        self.start.pack()

    def start_epidemic(self):
        self.canvas.delete('all')
        self.infection_radius = (self.infection_rate/2)
        self.this_world = World(self.height, self.width, 30, self.infection_rate)
        for person in self.this_world.get_people():
            x, y = person.get_location()
            if person.infection == True:
                self.canvas.create_oval(x,y, x+self.infection_radius, y+self.infection_radius, fill="red")
            else:
                self.canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+3, y+3, fill="yellow")
        self.update_epidemic()
```

And the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Eva Morris/Documents/computing/epidemic/epidemicui.py", line 76, in <module>
    my_gui = MyEpidemicModel(root)
  File "c:/Users/Eva Morris/Documents/computing/epidemic/epidemicui.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.infection_radius = (self.infection_rate/2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'IntVar' and 'int'
```

Comment: `IntVar` needs to be `IntVar()`

Comment: Please type the code and the error message in the question instead of providing pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set up an `IntVar`:

```
self.infection_rate = IntVar()
self.rate = Scale(orient='horizontal', from_=0, to=100, variable=self.infection_rate)
```

it is not a *Python variable*:

```
    self.infection_radius = (self.infection_rate/2)
    self.this_world = World(self.height, self.width, 30, self.infection_rate)
```

but rather *a Tkinter variable* -- you need to use `.get()` and `.set()` to access its value:

```
    self.infection_radius = (self.infection_rate.get() / 2)
    self.this_world = World(self.height, self.width, 30, self.infection_rate.get())
```